# Guardar select recuperado en mysql sin hacer click en el select

Tags: php, mysql, select, post

Excelente grupo de consulta y apoyo. Disculpas d antemano por no poner el código pero a lo mejor me pueden orientar sin necesidad de colocarlo pq es muy largo. La cuestión es que en mi código PHP guardo el Select o combobox en la tabla de Mysql perfectamente. Cuando vuelvo a llamar el articulo por decirlo así me recupera los datos y el valor del select correctamente pero si no toco el select al guardarlo me lo graba en blanco como si no estuviera recuperando el value. Algún consejo o artículo donde pueda orientarme ?

aqui los recupero :

```
                            <?php
                                if(isset($result1)){
                                    $codigo = $result1[0]["codigo"];
                                    $uno=mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM colegios WHERE codigo='$codigo'");
                                    $arr=mysqli_fetch_array($uno);
                                    $cur=$arr['coltoga'];
                                    $consulta=("SELECT * FROM colores ORDER BY codigo");
                                    $resultad=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);
                                    echo "<select name='colort' id='colort' disabled='disabled'>";
                                    echo "<option value='-1'>Escoja Color</option>";
                                    while($registro=mysqli_fetch_array($resultad)) {
                                        $id_c=$registro['codigo'];
                                        if ($cur == $id_c){
                                            $selected = 'selected';
                                        }else{
                                            $selected = '';
                                        }
                                        echo "<option value='".$registro['codigo']."' $selected>".$registro['nombre']."</option>";
                                    }
                                    echo "</select>";
                                }else{
                                    echo "<select name='colort' id='colort' disabled='disabled'>";
                                    echo "<option value='-1'>Escoja Color</option>";
                                    $selected = '';
                                    foreach ($resultc as $key => $value) {
                                        echo "<option value='".$value['codigo']."' $selected>".$valueo['nombre']."</option>";
                                    }
                                    echo "</select>";
                                }
                            ?>
```

y aqui lo grabo en la tabla:

```
    include ('abrir_conexion.php'); 

    $fecha_actual=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $codigo = $_POST["codigo"];
    $nomcol = $_POST["nomcol"];
    $jornada=$_POST["jornada"];
    $direccion = $_POST["direccion"];
    $telefono = $_POST["telefono"];
    $almacen=$_POST["almacen"];
    $vendedor = $_POST["codven"];
    $rector = $_POST["rector"];
    $contacto = $_POST["contacto"];
    $cargo = $_POST["cargo"];
    $colort= trim($_POST["colort"]);
    if (!empty($colort)){
        $colort=$_POST["colort"];
    }else{
        $colort="";
    }

    $colorc= trim($_POST["colorc"]);
    if (!empty($colorc)){
        $colorc=$_POST["colorc"];
    }else{
        $colorc="";
    }
    $colorbt= trim($_POST["colorbt"]);
    if (!empty($colorbt)){
        $colorbt=$_POST["colorbt"];
    }else{
        $colorbt="";
    }

    $tipov= trim($_POST["tipov"]);
    if (!empty($tipov)){
        $tipov=$_POST["tipov"];
    }else{
        $tipov="";
    }
    $colorbf= trim($_POST["colorbf"]);
    if (!empty($colorbf)){
        $colorbf=$_POST["colorbf"];
    }else{
        $colorbf="";
    }

    $colorves= trim($_POST["colorv"]);
    if (!empty($colorves)){
        $colorves=$_POST["colorv"];
    }else{
        $colorves="";
    }
    $colorcor= trim($_POST["colorcor"]);
    if (!empty($colorcor)){
        $colorcor=$_POST["colorcor"];
    }else{
        $colorcor="";
    }

    $fecha1 = "";
    $fecgra = "";
    if (isset($_POST["fecha1"])){
        $fecha1 = $_POST["fecha1"];
        $fecgra = invertDate($fecha1);    
    }
    $fecha2 = "";
    $fecent = "";
    if (isset($_POST["fecha2"])){
        $fecha2 = $_POST["fecha2"];
        $fecent = invertDate($fecha2);    
    }
    $fecha3 = "";
    $fecdev = "";
    if (isset($_POST["fecha3"])){
        $fecha3 = $_POST["fecha3"];
        $fecdev = invertDate($fecha3);    
    }
    $formatos='';
    if(isset($_POST['cosas'])) {
        $formatos = implode(',',$_POST['cosas']);
    }   
    $verificar_colegio = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM colegios WHERE codigo = '$codigo'");
    $filas2 = mysqli_num_rows($verificar_colegio);
    if ($filas2 > 0){
        $actual_colegio = "UPDATE colegios Set   nombre='$nomcol', direc='$direccion', tele='$telefono', rector='$rector', contacto='$contacto', cargo='$cargo', almacen='$almacen', vendor='$vendedor', jornada='$jornada', coltoga = '$colort', codbufa='$colorbf', colves='$colorves', tipoves='$tipov', tipbot='$colorbt', colcam='$colorc', codcorba='$colorcor', fecgrado = '$fecgra', fecentrega= '$fecent', fechadev = '$fecdev', referencia='$formatos', usuario='$user', fuso = '$fecha_actual' WHERE codigo = '$codigo'"; 
        $resultado2=mysqli_query($conexion,$actual_colegio);
        if (!$resultado2){
            echo '<script>
            alert("Colegio Sin Actualizar");
            window.history.go(-1);
            </script>';
            die("Conexión Fallida");
        }else{
            include ('cerrar_conexion.php');
            echo '<script>
            alert("Colegio Actualizado");
            window.history.go(-1);
            </script>';
            exit;
        }
```

está incompletp aqui pero funciona bien para grabar por primera vez y recuperar la información pero si no toco el Select me lo graba en blanco. Ayuda por favor.

Comment: ¿Qué significa *si no toco el select me lo guarda en blanco*? En ese caso, se estaría enviando `-1` como value que parece ser el primer `option`.

Comment: O sea, el valor recuperado de la tabla me lo muestra en el select. Hasta ahi todo bien. Si hago click en el select lo graba también pero los select que tienen su valor recuperado pero no los actualizo ni los cambio me los graba en blanco como si no tuvieran el value seleccionado.